# extenstion theorem of solution for ode in hartman

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

[image]

This is first theorem of extension theorem of solution of ode in hartman.

I wonder the exact meaning of last part "thus $(b_1,y(b_1)),(b_2,y(b_2)),...$ is unbound or has a cluster point in $\partial E$".

I read this part as "if the sequence $(b_1,y(b_1)),(b_2,y(b_2)),...$ is bounded, they have convergent subsequence, so this part imply each convergent subsequence can be converge other points, but their limit point should be in $\partial E$ ".

but I cannot have convince about my understanding.

"Maybe that sequence converges?" if we can say  $(b_1,y(b_1)),\cdots$ convergent sequecne,
the story is completely different.

the above sequence is convergent sequence? or Is my understanding correct?

corollary 2.1.
Let $f(t,y)$ be continuous on an open $(t,y)$-set $E$ and satisfy $|f(t,y)|\leq M$. Let $E_0$ be a compact subset of $E$. Then there exists an $\alpha>0$, depending on $E,E_0,M,$ with the property that if $(t_0,y_0)\in E_0$, then $(1.1)$ has a solution on $|t-t_0|\leq \alpha$.

Comment: Could you check the proof of Corollary 2.1 for the situation that $(t_0,y_0)$ is on the boundary of $E_0$. Does it then really provide a local solution that is partially outside $E_0$, and possibly even outside $E$?

Comment: Actually in book , let $a=dist(E_0,\partial E)$, and let $\alpha=\min(a,a/M)$, here $ dist$ imply distance between two set. So local solution can be exist in $E$  (partially outside$ E_0$)

Comment: Ok, so the box or cylinder $|t-t_0|<α$, $\|y-y_0\|<a$ is inside $E$. The existence theorem then applies to this box, not $E_0$, and everything is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nested sequence of subsets $E_n\subset E_{n+1}\subset\dots\subset E$ that exhausts $E$ and where every $\bar E_n$ is compact. Also, $(b_k,y(b_k))$ are outside $E_n$ for $k\ge n$.

Any cluster point of the sequence can not be an inner point of $E$, as it would be then also an inner point of some subset $E_n$. Which is impossible as the subsequence converging to the cluster point is mainly outside of $E_n$.

So the only location that remains for the cluster point is the boundary of $E$.

Comment: Is the definition of Cluster point you use "$(b_0,y(b_0))$ is cluster point of sequence if any neighborhood of $(b_0,y(b_0))$ contain at least one point of sequence"? Is it correct we cannot say above seqeunce converge ,however if there exist any convergent subsequence of that sequence they should converge a point in $\partial E$?

Comment: Actually I wonder if above sequence is bounded, we can say above sequence are convergent sequence.

Comment: Yes and yes. Because of bounded and compactness, there exists a cluster point, with one or, consequently, an infinity of sequence points in any small neighborhood. As all but the first $n$ points are outside $E_n$, the sequence is "squeezed" towards the boundary, the location $E\setminus E_n$ becoming ever thinner.

Comment: Sorry to ask you repeately , I want to understand the theorem more clearly, Is it correct that "there exist many cluster points (more than one) of sequence, but they should be on boundary of E?"

Comment: Sorry for asking the same question over and over again

Comment: Yes, a sequence can have many cluster points. Any enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ has any point of that interval as cluster point. The solution of a DE will in general be a little more regular.

Comment: Thank you always for your kind reply. I'm clearly understand what you mean.